# Can the [くん]{kun} suffix be used for non-binary people?

Tags: suffixes, gender

I recently played a videogame with a non-binary character and wanted to affectionately refer to them as [ロワン]{Rowan}[くん]{kun} but realized that this suffix is normally applied to males.

I also found an answer mentioning that kun is normally used for males/masculine identifying people [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32819/27180).

Is there an alternative suffix that I could use or would [くん]{kun} still be appropriate even for non-binary people?

Comment: The くん suffix can actually be used for women as well, though it's less common especially in real life. In fiction people who use くん for women tend to be figures of some authority, usually on the older side, keeping a professional distance.

Comment: English (or most languages) should have the same issue: is calling a non-binary with _Mr._ appropriate?

Comment: @sundowner Since I am a native English speaker, I know English has _Mx._ as an option for non-binary folks (or if you aren't non-binary but don't want to specify your gender at all), although it's not widely adopted. I also wasn't sure if the くん suffix was ungendered itself even though it is mostly used for males/masculine identifying people, because other suffixes (such as さん, たん, ちゃん) are not gendered (at least according to the understanding I have of them).

Comment: くん used for non-males sounds so old-school (like early 20th century) since old teachers often called students with くん. For example, in a cutscene of an old animation [パンダコパンダ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panda!_Go,_Panda!) (Panda! Go, Panda!), the teacher refers to the heroine [ミミ子]{mi mi ko} as ミミ子くん.

Comment: Good to know @puhitaku! Thanks for the extra context.